APScheduler+Kubernetes, Error getting due jobs from job store 'default': Authentication required
I'm a beginner for kubernetes and trying to use APScheduler with FastAPI in Kubernetes. The jobs are stored in redis.
FastAPI with APScheduler is running in pod A, Redis is running in pod B, so I need to connect redis between pods.
For redis, when I disable the password, got the connection error from APScheduler, but with a password it still shows the error below.

WARNING  | logging:callHandlers:1706 - Error getting due jobs from job store 'default': Authentication required.

Redis yaml file in Kubernetes:
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: redis-config
  labels:
    app: redis
data:
  redis.conf: |-
    dir /srv
    port 6379
    bind 0.0.0.0
    appendonly yes
    daemonize no
    protected-mode yes
    requirepass ispassword
    pidfile /srv/redis-6379.pid

The code for scheduler:
REDIS = {
    'host': 'service-redis.default.svc.cluster.local',
    'port': 6379,
    'db': 5,
    'password': 'ispassword',
    'jobs_key': f'apscheduler.jobs.{settings.tsak_id}',
    'run_times_key': f'apscheduler.run_times.{settings.task_id}'
}
jobstores = {"default": RedisJobStore(**REDIS)}
Schedule = AsyncIOScheduler(jobstores=jobstores)

There is a pod with another fastapi container and I have tested, redis is connectable.
Does anyone knows the reason behind this error and who should I fix it? Or what I did wrong with kubernetes and APScheuler? Thank you for any advice.
